# Need to properly set USEREXIT and LOGARCHMETH1

Tags: db2

Running DB2 version 9.7 on Windows Server. I'm new to DB2, but not to databases in general.

My underlying problem is this error in the Event Viewer:

`ADM1848W  Failed to archive log file "S0000880.LOG" to "USEREXIT" from 
"C:\DB2\NODE0000\SQL00003\SQLOGDIR\".`

I don't want to user a USEREXIT program.

If I'm understanding what I've read correctly, the new method to specify a log archive method is to use LOGARCHMETH1. However some documentation (and some observed behavior) lead me to believe that it isn't that simple.

My current DB configuration is this:

`> get db config for $my_db
....
Log retain for recovery status                          = RECOVERY
User exit for logging status                            = YES
....
First log archive method                 (LOGARCHMETH1) = LOGRETAIN`

I'm trying to turn off USEREXIT with this :

`update db cfg for $my_db using userexit off`

but with no effect.

How can I set my db to use LOGRETAIN but not USEREXIT ?

And a follow up, if I do get this set correctly, is a backup required to complete the change?

Thanks!

Comment: You must at least deactivate and reactivated the database for changes in logging configuration to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran the update db command, followed by db2stop and db2start and the parameter remains unchanged.

Comment: It seems that if I reconnect to the database (I`m using the DB2 Command Window) then the correct parameter values appear.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have a complete understanding of the USEREXIT still, I solved it by turning all logging off, then turning it back on with these steps (db2 commands):

To turn off:

```
connect to $db
update database configuration for $db using logretain off
db2stop
db2start
```

Then, turning on on:

```
connect to $db
update database configuration for $db using logretain on
db2stop
db2start
db2 backup database $db to <filename> without prompting
```

Note: a backup is NOT required when turning logging OFF but IS REQUIRED when turning logging ON.